# associative arrays in openscad?

Tags: dictionary, openscad, 3d-printing

Does openscad have any language primitive for string-keyed associative arrays (a.k.a hash maps, a.k.a dictionaries)? Or is there any convention for how to emulate associative arrays?

So far all I can think of is using vectors and using variables to map indexes into the vector to human readable names. That means there's no nice, readable way to *define* the vector, you just have to comment it.

Imagine I want to write something akin to the Python data structure:

```
bobbin_metrics = {
   'majacraft': {
      'shaft_inner_diameter': 9.0,
      'shaft_outer_diameter': 19.5,
      'close_wheel_diameter': 60.1,
      # ...
   },
   'majacraft_jumbo': {
      'shaft_inner_diameter': 9.0,
      'shaft_outer_diameter': 25.0,
      'close_wheel_diameter': 100.0,
   },
   # ...
}
```

such that I can reference it in model definitions in some recognisably hash-map-like way, like passing `bobbin_metrics['majacraft']` to something as `metrics` and referencing `metrics['close_wheel_diameter']`.

So far my best effort looks like

```
# Vector indexes into bobbin-metrics arrays
BM_SHAFT_INNER_DIAMETER = 0
BM_SHAFT_OUTER_DIAMETER = 1
BM_CLOSE_WHEEL_DIAMETER = 2

bobbin_metrics_majacraft = [
    9.0,      # shaft inner diameter
    19.5,     # shaft outer diameter
    60.1,     # close-side wheel diameter
    # ....
];

bobbin_metrics_majacraft_jumbo = [
    9.0,      # shaft inner diameter
    25.0,     # shaft outer diameter
    100.0,     # close-side wheel diameter
    # ....
];

bobbin_metrics = [
    bobbin_metrics_majacraft,
    bobbin_metrics_majacraft_jumbo,
    # ...
];

# Usage when passed a bobbin metrics vector like
# bobbin_metrics_majacraft as 'metrics' to a function

    metrics[BM_SHAFT_INNER_DIAMETER]
```

I think that'll work. But it's *U.G.L.Y.*. Not quite "I write applications in `bash`" ugly, but not far off.

Is there a better way?

I'm prepared to maintain the data set outside openscad and have a generator for an include file if I have to, but I'd rather not.

---

Also, in honour of April 1 I miss the blink tag and wonder if the scrolling marquee will work? Tried 'em :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I played around with the OpenSCAD search() function which is documented in the manual here;

```
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Other_Language_Features#Search
```

The following pattern allows a form of associative list, it may not be optimal but does provide a way to set up a dictionary structure and retrieve a value against a string key;

```
// associative searching
// dp 2019
// - define the dictionary
dict = [
      ["shaft_inner_diameter", 9.0],
      ["shaft_outer_diameter", 19.5],
      ["close_wheel_diameter", 60.1]
      ];

// specify the serach term
term = "close_wheel_diameter";

// execute the search
find = search(term, dict);

// process results
echo("1", find);
echo ("2",dict[find[0]]);
echo ("3",dict[find[0]][1]);
```

The above produces;

```
Compiling design (CSG Tree generation)...
  WARNING: search term not found: "l"
...
  WARNING: search term not found: "r"
ECHO: "1", [2, 0]
ECHO: "2", ["close_wheel_diameter", 60.1]
ECHO: "3", 60.1
```

Personally, I would do this sort of thing in Python then generate the OpenSCAD as an intermediate file or maybe use the SolidPython library.

Comment: works on Archlinux, openscad 2015.03-3, but only with match patterns of max 15 chars

Comment: Thankyou very much. That's a great idea.

Comment: Just adding a comment here to point people towards the BOSL2 OpenSCAD library (in particular, it has "structs" which are essentially dictionaries as described above) - it provides a number of functions and modules that may be useful if you're at the point where you need to use dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

An example of a function that uses [`search()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Other_Language_Features#Search) and does not produce any warnings.

```scad
available_specs = [
  ["mgn7c", 1,2,3,4],
  ["mgn7h", 2,3,4,5],
];

function selector(item) = available_specs[search([item], available_specs)[0]];

chosen_spec = selector("mgn7c");

echo("Specification was returned from function", chosen_spec);
```

The above will produce the following output:

```
ECHO: "Specification was returned from function", ["mgn7c", 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Another very similar approach is using [list comprehensions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/List_Comprehensions) with a condition statement, just like you would in Python for example. Does the same thing, looks a bit simpler.

```scad
function selector(item) = [
  for (spec = available_specs)
  if (spec[0] == item)
  spec
];
```

Comment: Really neat solution, works like a charm! I tweaked the function it slightly to also take any "available specs": `function selector(item, dict) = dict[search([item], dict)[0]];`